# create map in groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I have the below file :

```
name = David 
city = sydney
COuntry = Australia
```

I am trying to create a hash map using groovy and split it at `=` and store it in an array such that `part[0]` contains before equal and `part[1]` contains after equal. I am then trying to create a map here .

**Desired output :**

```
def mapedData = [name :david , city : sydney , country :australia ]
```

**My try :**

```
String s=""
def myfile = new File("C:/Users/.............")
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myfile));

Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
while((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if(!s.startsWith("#")) {
        StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(s, "=")
            while(st.hasMoreElements()) {
                String line=st.nextElement().toString().trim()
                print line
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand the actual problem here. Where are you assigning the values in `map`? What are you currently getting as an output?

Comment: @jane have you tried with my code .. ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create a map from a file in Groovy, you can use `java.util.Properties` for that. Here is an example:

```
def file = new File("C:\\stackoverflow\\props.properties")
def props = new Properties()
file.withInputStream { stream ->
    props.load(stream)
}
println(props)
```

This prints out:

```
[key1:value1, key2:value2]
```

The `props.properties` file contains this:

```
# Stackoverflow test
key1 = value1
key2 = value2
```

Comment: Thanks for the input . This is solving the issue . But its not fetching all the values from the file and printing in the array . Is is because it contains "#' in between as comment ?

Comment: If I understand your question: yes. Any line which starts with "#" will be ommitted. Lines starting with "#" are comments, like the one above: `# Stackoverflow test`

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code:

```
def map =[:]
new File("file.txt").eachLine{line->
if(line.contains('=')&& (!line.startsWith("#"))){        
    map[line.split('=')[0]]=line.split('=')[1]
    }
}
println map
```

Comment: Getting this error : expecting ')', found '}' @ line 3, column 1.
      }}
       ^

Comment: @jane Sorry my mistake. i have fixed that. now try with this

Answer (score 0):

Here a one-liner that does what you want:

```
new File(/C:\Users\.............\input.txt/).readLines().collectEntries { it.trim().split(/\s*=\s*/) as List }
```